# Customize (or create) Add New in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am writing a plugin and I want to customize the Add new post button (or create a new one) to get the current url. I am new to all this and I am not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Are you asking to add a new custom post type to your website via your plugin?